# Pip doesn't install when it says it has

Tags: python, pip

I ask pip to install a package.  It *says* that it installed it, but it's not there!

```
$ virtualenv --python python3 asdf
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/app/asdf/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/app/asdf/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

$ . asdf/bin/activate

$ pip install pygments
Collecting pygments
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/ee/b6e02dc6529e82b75bb06823ff7d005b141037cb1416b10c6f00fc419dca/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.2.0

$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        10.0.1 
setuptools 39.1.0 
wheel      0.31.1
```

Pip version is `10.0.1` and this is a Amazon Linux (CentOS) system.  There *are* the files you'd expect at `asdf/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/pygments/`, but nothing in `asdf/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.  I have no idea what's going on here.  Will someone please help?

Comment: What does `which pip` say? Does `python -m pip` in place of `pip` work?

Comment: `which pip` says `~/asdf/bin/pip` and running `python -m pip install pygments` claims the package is already installed.

Comment: And is `which python` also `~/asdf/bin/python`? Also, what about `python -m pip list`?

Comment: `which python` returns `~/asdf/bin/python` and `python -m pip list` returns `pip`, `setuptools`, and `wheel`.